# Stop JTextArea from expanding

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to read information off of a data file and process it into a `JTextArea` for an about file for a term project that I'm making. The problem is that when I do `scanner.nextLine()` it's expanding the text area to fit the text and what I wanted was it to keep the size of the text area the same and if it runs out of space on the current line to start on the

```
    if(event.getSource() == forward)
    {
        text.setText(s.nextLine());
    }
```

The text area is setup like this:

```
     text = new JTextArea(11, 30);
```

Basically what I want to know is if there's a method that text area offers (I looked) that relocates space to the next line if the current is full. I can most likely just edit the data file if there isn't a way to do it in the text area.

Answer (score 10):

Place the `JTextArea` within a `JScrollPane` and add the scroll pane to your container instead

```
text = new JTextArea(11, 30);
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(text);
//...
add(scrollpane);
```

See [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

This will prevent the scroll pane from growing in the current container.

Also check out `JTextArea#setLineWrap` and `JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord` which will effect how the component treats text that would exceed the viewable width.

See [How to use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JTextArea#setLineWrap(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap(boolean)) by default is set to false.

> Sets the line-wrapping policy of the text area. If set to true the
>   lines will be wrapped if they are too long to fit within the allocated
>   width. If set to false, the lines will always be unwrapped. A
>   PropertyChange event ("lineWrap") is fired when the policy is changed.
>   By default this property is false.

Also see this method [JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap(boolean))

Example a SSCCE:

```
   public class JTextAreaTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(11,30);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setText("Hi how are you? Im testing this textarea and im seeing if it's wrapping words");
        textArea.append("SASASASASDASDASDASDASDASDADSASDASDASDASDAS");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image: textArea example]